# Dialogflow endpoint type in typescript

Tags: typescript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've implemented a webhook for Dialogflow in Typescript and I would like my endpoint for Google to only support the Dialogflow SDK object. Currently my controller looks something like this:

```
import {dialogflow, DialogflowConversation} from "actions-on-google";

export class GoogleController {
  public endpoint: any;

constructor() {
  this.endpoint = dialogflow();
  this.endpoint.intent("Welcome", (conv: DialogflowConversation) => {
    return conv.ask("Hey There");
  });
};
```

Currently I've made the endpoint be of type any, but I would like to change this to a Dialogflow object. I've tried importing DialogflowApp objects from the SDK, but those don't seem to work. Either they don't match the object returned by the dialogflow() call or the interface doesn't have the .intent function.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening up a project in VSCode, I wrote:

```
import { dialogflow } from 'actions-on-google'

const endpoint = dialogflow()
```

Hovering over `endpoint`, VSCode shows me some metadata on the variable:

`const endpoint: OmniHandler & BaseApp & DialogflowApp<{}, {}, Contexts, DialogflowConversation<{}, {}, Contexts>>`

Maybe your `DialogflowApp` declaration needs the generics, or maybe you can just copy that string directly.

Comment: Yup, the declaration needed the generics. I improved it a bit by created an empty interface which extended the string that you mentioned, now I can just use my DialogflowEndpoint interface instead of the long string.